# Is NSComparisonResult needed, whats it doing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Something that I noticed today, why would you cast `NSOrderedSame` to `NSComparisonResult`?

```
return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
```

I usually write

```
return NSOrderedSame;
```

But was curious if there was something I was missing and a reason for adding the cast?

Comment: How you declare return type of your function ?

Comment: There is no need for a cast as long as the return type is `NSComparisonResult`.